# Can I use Silverlight to offload math operations on the GPU?

Tags: silverlight, opencl, gpu, silverlight-5.0

I'm interested in GPU offloading and think that Silverlight might be able to offload calculations onto the GPU in a multi-platform manner.

Is this possible?  What are some sample libraries that I can use?

Is there any chance Silverlight will use OpenCL?

Comment: By multi-platform, do you mean OS or GPU vendor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question looks like a troll but I'll answer it though ;)

> Is this possible? What are some sample libraries that I can use?

For Windows only you might be able to hack using SL 4 COM interop capabilities but I won't count on it.

Silverlight is not multi-platform : runs full-featured on Windows, limited on MAC, and with a development lag on Linux/Unix... via the Moonlight project not provided by Microsoft.

> Is there any chance Silverlight will use OpenCL?

No, Silverlight is dead, and has never been really alive (I too have invested a lot of time in this technology for almost nothing :() and chances are SL5 will be the last version.

So your best bet is to use cross-platform technologies like **Java** and its OpenCL binding **JavaCL** : http://code.google.com/p/javacl/ using **Applets** or **JWS** deployment.

Comment: You forgot to mention that Moonlight has been canceled before it was even getting feature parity, so this kind of multi-platform support is gone.

Answer (score 2):

For GPU offloading (in the web browser context), you should look into WebGL and WebCL. I may be biased, but proprietary plug-ins like Flash, Silverlight and Java are pretty much dead in the water.

Answer (score 1):

Even discarding the fact that Silverlight 5 is probably the last version, there is currently no chance of Microsoft supporting OpenCL/CUDA/etc... inside it.

You might get DirectX features, as they support currently custom shaders (HLSL) in some configurations, but not vendor specific (CUDA) or competing (OpenCL) technology.